# Who judged season one?

Tags: jump-city-seattle

[*Jump City: Seattle*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1842724/) often alluded to the judges, however they were never seen nor announced. I understand the show was tied into the **Pro Parkour League** but couldn't find anything on either G4's site or the PPL's (Sort of) sites. The credits didn't seem to indicate either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**We don't know**.

I'm aware this is a non-answer, but this has been my Everest on this site for some time now! I've searched high and low and there is simply no existing information on who the judges were. Unless an active participant of the show sees this post and adds the answer, I don't think we'll ever know. The show never mentioned it, none of the associated wikis or website ever mentioned it and even the (few) fan forums for parkour never question who the judges are.

So simply put: we don't know and are highly unlikely to ever know.